# For $k \times n$ matrices $X,Y$, when do we have $X = AY$ for $A \in \operatorname{Gl}(k, \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}_{k,n}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of $k \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. Let  $\operatorname{Gl}(k, \mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all $k \times k$ invertible matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose we have $X,Y \in \mathcal{M}_{k,n}(\mathbb{R})$ ($k\le n$), and let us denote the rows of $X$ and $Y$ by $x_1, \dots, x_k$ and $y_1, \dots, y_k$ respectively. Furthermore, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are both of rank $k$ (so that the rows of $X$ are linearly independent, and the same for the rows of $Y$). 
Using $X$ and $Y$, we can naturally form a matrix $Z_{X,Y} \in \mathcal{M}_{2k,n}(\mathbb{R})$ with rows $x_1, \dots, x_k, y_1, \dots y_k$.

Here is the statement I'm looking to establish: if $Z_{X,Y}$ has some $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ minor that's equal to $0$, then there exists $A \in \operatorname{Gl}(k, \mathbb{R})$ such that $AX = Y$. I really have not gotten very far with this problem, as my linear algebra background is a bit weak. I guess I must somehow start with the $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ sub-matrix that produces the vanishing minor, and construct the needed A.

If you are curious about why the heck I want to prove such a statement--this is related to a homework problem in differential geometry that I am working on. Having this fact will allow me to show that the classic Grassman manifold $G(k,n)$ of $k$-planes through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in fact Hausdorff.

I am mostly just looking for hints since this is a step in a homework problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need $k < n$ for this to even make sense, because otherwise you don't have minors of order $k+1$. Note that this will still not make your statement true.

Comment: @VedranŠego - Gotcha. Thanks for your help. Let's just put this question to rest for awhile until I can figure out what statement I actually need to prove :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k = 1$, $n = 2$, $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $Y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = Y = AX = A \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

yields a contradiction, so there is no such $A$. But,

$$Z_{X,Y} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

is of order $2 \times 2$, so its only minor of order $k+1 = 2$ is $\det Z_{X,Y} = 0$, meaning that the statement from the question is false. This will happen whenever $X = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ and $Y \ne 0$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I am thinking I need to add the condition that both $X,Y$ are of rank $k$.

Comment: Wouldn't work: $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $Y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. You'll have the same minor, and the same problem, with both $X$ and $Y$ having ranks $k$.